# How to set MVC binding correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There is a `controller`:

```
[Route("Socket")]
public class SocketController : Controller
{
    [Route("New")]
    public ActionResult NewSocketForm()
    {
        ViewBag.ChargeTypes = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem("bla", "0"),
            new SelectListItem("bla2", "1")
        };
        var model = new Model();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

There is a `View`:

```
@model blabla.Model

<div class="soket-item">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ChargeType" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="ChargeType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ChargeTypes" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ChargeType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and there is a `Model`:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Charge Type")]
    public int ChargeType { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 problems :

- `asp-items` does not load the list from the `ViewBag`
- `label` does not load Display Name from `Model`
  Why?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the tag-helpers aren't executing. Do you have a *_ViewImports.cshtml* file that includes `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available))?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, I have `Pages\\_ViewImports.cshtml` but my View located in `Views` directory.

Comment: Do you also have a *Views\\_ViewImports.cshtml* file? The *Pages* version doesn't apply to the *Views* folder.

Comment: @KirkLarkin No, I don't https://i.stack.imgur.com/88izq.png

Comment: In that case, add it yourself. Make sure it's got the `@addTagHelper` line I showed above.

Comment: @KirkLarkin that is it! it works now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First time in model define a property for asp-items:

```
  public class Model
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> ListChargeType{ get; set; }
    }
```

then fill this property in controller:

```
 [Route("New")]
    public ActionResult NewSocketForm()
    {
        
        var model = new Model();
        List<SelectListItem> lstChargeTypes= new  List<SelectListItem>();
        lstChargeTypes.Add( new SelectListItem {Value= "0", Text = "bla" });
        lstChargeTypes.Add( new SelectListItem {Value= "1", Text = "bla2" });

        var model = new Model();
        model.ListChargeType= lstChargeTypes;
        return View(model);
    }
```

then in view :

```
@model blabla.Model

<div class="soket-item">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ChargeType" class="control-label">@ChargeType</label>
        <select asp-for="ChargeType" class="form-control" asp-items="ListChargeType" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ChargeType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```